Module Federation in Angular with the new build system
With Angular 18 transitioning away from Webpack to the new Angular CLI Build System, how can I implement Module Federation or a similar micro-frontend architecture without relying on Webpack? Are there alternative approaches or configurations that allow code sharing between independent Angular applications using the new build process?

We can implement module federation via 2 ways :

Code base in same repository : In this approach, we have a shell application and multiple  remote application in same repository.
Different repository - In this approach application will be in different repository and we have to make main application as shell application where we can have other remote applications.

In module federation, as we know that application will run independently so that, to transfer the data between the application we can have a shared angular library and can have the common and shared logic there. All application can install the library and we can share the data.

Thank you for the answer. I need, or is looking for a more detailed answer that tells me how this should/could be done without WebPack. At least some references or links that shows the difference between the WebPack-way and the alternative.

Perhaps this can help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/native-federation

Yes, thats what I'm looking for. I think. I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Native federation isn't production ready.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
